# How to close dropdown on click outside React TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a dropdown & I need to use this dropdown in multiple places in single page.

When I open any dropdown then rest of the dropdown should be close. How can I fix this issue ?

My code:
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdownoutsideissue-tx2lqr?file=/src/Dropdown.tsx)

Comment: You need to add a click event listener to the document root, a ref to your dropdown root, and then check `event.target` to find out if the click originated inside your dropdown or outside of it.

Comment: This question is off-topic too, same as the other one. As a matter of longstanding policy, code needs to be in the question itself. Voting to close for now. Please repair it when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Dropdown = () => {
  const [actionIsOpen, setActionIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const actionList = [
    { id: "1", name: "One" },
    { id: "2", name: "Two" },
    { id: "3", name: "Three" },
    { id: "4", name: "Four" }
  ];

  const handleActionClick = () => {
    setActionIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="tw-relative">
        <span onMouseDown={handleActionClick} className="tw-cursor-pointer">
          <button onBlur={() => setActionIsOpen(false)}>Dropdown Click</button>
        </span>
        {actionIsOpen && (
          <div className="shadow tw-w-48 tw-absolute tw-top-2 tw-z-50 tw-left-4 tw-bg-white tw-pt-2">
            {actionList.map((val: any) => (
              <div
                key={val.id}
                className="tw-bg-white-100 hover:tw-bg-violet-100 hover:tw-text-violet-900 tw-cursor-pointer hover:tw-font-bold py-2 px-3 tw-text-gray-600"
              onMouseDown={() => alert(val.name)}
              >
                {val.name}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Something like this ?

Comment: and if you want to get value when clicking "0ne" "Two" etc 

 <div
                key={val.id}
                className="tw-bg-white-100 hover:tw-bg-violet-100 hover:tw-text-violet-900 tw-cursor-pointer hover:tw-font-bold py-2 px-3 tw-text-gray-600"
              onMouseDown={() => alert(val.name)}>
                {val.name}
              </div>

Comment: This will work but it will make it frustrating to switch between the open lists since clicking on another button immediately closes the open dropdown and moves the buttons. (To make it clear, open Dropdown 1 and then click on Dropdown 4)

Comment: but if i'm changing button to simple div then its not working...

Comment: one another issue found if i'm using onBlur then I'm not able to click on dropdown list text

Comment: The solution in this answer will not work correctly. it will close the dropdown as soon as the user clicks into the dropdown area.

Comment: Sorry for late response you can look at the first command it by that code you can Click dropdown item

Comment: @Neo I'm not understand what you want to say?

Comment: i implented code for selecting dropdown items