# React-Select taking time to open dropdown when data is approximately 10000

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select but if data approximately 10000 dropdown is taking time to open. How can I fix this?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-heavy-data-8yljwp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: By not using a select that loads all those options to begin with, but implementing some sort of autocomplete-search instead ...

Comment: actually in entire application using react-select so we cant change it.

Comment: Well then you'll probably have to live with it ... Even without any JS applied on top of it, a standard select field with so many options is likely to make the browser struggle already. (https://www.google.com/search?q=html+select+field+1000+options+slow+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Note that this is off-topic because the relevant code is not in the question itself. Most code sandboxes are prohibited in Stack Overflow questions unless the question also features code, but unfortunately codesandbox.io has not been added to that list. It can be assumed that adding this is not seen as a product development priority for Stack Overflow, but the rules on a self-contained question do still hold.

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) for more information.

Comment: I am downvoting this question, since i have raised this with you twice before. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76629821) and [here is a second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76628463).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known performance issue with react-select. There's [an open PR to fix this](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/5648). We need to wait for it to be merged. One workaround for this is to overwrite `MenuList` component using `react-window`. Here's [the example of this method](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-heavy-data-forked-znl5xl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) applied to your sample code.